# Microsoft Visual Studio: How to find where a dll is loaded from?

Tags: dll, path

A wrong version of a dll (MSVCR90d.dll instead of MSVCR90.dll) gets used for the delete operator, causing a crash. In the callstack, only the dll name is shown, not their path. How to see the path?

Edit: I'm building in Release mode, not in debug mode. So why does the debug dll get used? I have seen the same problem reported on many other websites, but could find no working solution.
Yesterday I found using Dependency Walker that the debug dll is getting picked up, so I renamed the dll, then the release version got picked up in the Dependency Walker, and also my program did not crash. I didn't change anything today, but the program has started crashing again. And when I see the dependency walker tree, it shows MSVCR90d.dll (the debug dll) with a question mark, saying it couldn't find it in the path. Why can't it pick up the release dll? Also I don't know from where the debug dll gets used by the runtime.

Comment: Did, any of the answers work for you? If not, did you find any other solution? If yes, you should post that here and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add them in your global PATH environment variable. [Refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173406.aspx)
2. You can specify the dll manually by right clicking on the solution and selecting Add Reference, then browse to the particular dll.
3. You can add the path to the DLLs to the Executables files settings under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories

Comment: I agree with @Ozair Kafray's reply too!!

Comment: Hey Jayesh, please find my edited question with more details. I added a reference to the directory containing the Release dll, but still no change in the runtime behaviour, I don't know where the debug dll gets picked up from, or why the debug dll gets used even, since I have built my program in Release mode.

Comment: It should not pick the wrong one normally. Kindly use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool to analyze the route your web app takes....

Answer (score 0):

For finding out the details of a dll, you might want to use [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com/)

However, in your case I think `d` is being appended to the name of `dll`, probably because you are creating a `DEBUG` build, and for that corresponding `DEBUG` versions of all `dlls` are loaded.

If you choose to create a `RELEASE` build, you would not have a `d` appended to MSVCR90.dll

Comment: I've created a Release build (with debug symbols enabled), not a Debug build. I don't know why the debug version of MSVCR90d.dll gets picked up.

Comment: I think that would make VS to use debug version too. Try once without it, and that would confirm it. You can then repost a new question or modify this accordingly, to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: I just tried after removing the debug options in the compiler and linker settings, but still facing the same problem. The debug dll gets used and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know Dll path, you need to understand why Debug version of delete operator is called. Maybe, _DEBUG constant is defined in Release configuration.